# Replacing Captured Groups in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, vba

Is it possible to do something like the following:

```
Sub GetANewDirectory()
    Dim MyString As String
    MyString = "C:\File1\File2\File3\AnImportantFile.txt"

    Dim MyRegEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    With MyRegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = ".*(File1)\\(File2)\\(File3).*"
    End With

    Dim MyMatch As Variant        
    Set MyMatch = MyRegEx.Execute(MyString)

    ' The following syntax doesn't work
    MyMatch(0).SubMatches(0) = Func1(MyMatch(0).SubMatches(0))
    MyMatch(0).SubMatches(1) = Func2(MyMatch(0).SubMatches(1))
    MyMatch(0).SubMatches(2) = Func3(MyMatch(0).SubMatches(2))

    Debug.Print MyMatch(0)
    ' My desired result is:
    ' C:\File1Apple\File2Banna\File3Mango\AnImportantFile.txt
End Sub

Function Func1(Arg1 As String) As String
    Func1 = Arg1  & "Apple"
End Function

Function Func2(Arg1 As String) As String
    Func2 = Arg1 & "Banna"
End Function

Function Func3(Arg1 As String) As String
    Func3 = Arg1 & "Mango"
End Function
```

My apologies if this seems a bit abstract, but I have a real need for something like this. I am certain that I can accomplish the task without regular expressions, but I can see where this kind of feature could be useful.

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot directly assign a value to a submatch

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the usage of external functions to handle the operation, then your best option (with a regular expression) is to pass a function pointer into the `.Replace` method of the `RegExp` object. This function will receive as argument:

1. The part of the string that matched the pattern in the `RegExp`
2. One argument for each of the capture groups in the pattern
3. The offset inside the original string where the pattern matched
4. The original string

The function must return the string that will replace the part of the original string that matched the pattern.

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyString
    MyString = "C:\File1\File2\File3\AnImportantFile.txt"

    With New RegExp
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        ' groups:     (1     )  (2     )  (3     )
        .Pattern = "\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)\\([^\\]+)\\"
        MyString = .Replace(MyString, GetRef("ReplaceHandler"))
    End With 

    WScript.Echo MyString


Function ReplaceHandler( matchedString, group1, group2, group3, offset, originalString )
    ReplaceHandler = Join(Array("", Func1(group1), Func2(group2), Func3(group3), ""), "\")
End Function    

Function Func1( Arg1 ) 
    Func1 = Arg1  & "Apple"
End Function
Function Func2( Arg1 ) 
    Func2 = Arg1 & "Banna"
End Function
Function Func3( Arg1 ) 
    Func3 = Arg1 & "Mango"
End Function
```